# LINQ Case statement with COUNT and GROUP

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, linq

Can you help me translate this Mysql into Linq please :

```
SELECT distcode, COUNT(cid) as count_all_case
,count(case when labid = 1 then cid end) as count_id1
,count(case when labid = 2 then cid end) as count_id2
,count(case when labid = 3 then cid end) as count_id3 
FROM labcase
WHERE SEQ is not NULL AND date_serv BETWEEN 20160101 AND 20161001
GROUP BY distcode
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you'd need to look at the generated SQL, but the filtering and grouping parts are simple - it's only the counting bit that's particularly tricky. You can probably do that within the projection of the group:

```
var start = new DateTime(2016, 1, 1);
var end = new DateTime(2016, 10, 1);
var query = from labCase in db.LabCase
            where labCase.Seq != null &&
                labCase.DateServ >= start &&
                labCase.DateServ <= end
            group labCase by labCase.DistCode into g
            select new
            {
                DistCode = g.Key,
                CountId1 = g.Count(x => x.LabId == 1),
                CountId2 = g.Count(x => x.LabId == 2),
                CountId3 = g.Count(x => x.LabId == 3)
            };
```

Comment: should the date clause in your where clause not be labCase.date_serv?  Most likely just a typo

Comment: @Ctrl_Alt_Defeat: Yup, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Lambda Query

```
var query = db.labcase
        .Where(p => p.SEQ != null && p.date_serv >=  new Datetime(2016,01,01) && p.date_serv <= new Datetime(2016,01,10))
        .GroupBy(f => new {distcode}
                , (key , elem) => new {
    key.distcode
    ,count_id1 =  elem.Count(x => x.LabId == 1)
    ,count_id2 =  elem.Count(x => x.LabId == 2)
    ,count_id3 =  elem.Count(x => x.LabId == 3)
})
```