# Error while using Group By in LinQ

Tags: c#, linq

i am relatively new to Linq and am trying to group by my Linq query but am getting the error that does not contain Field value.

Below is my linq query. Can anyone please help me on this.

```
var name = dt1.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(p => (int)p["Age"] >= 29)
    .GroupBy(p =>p.Field<string>("Role"))
    .Select(p => new{ID = p.Field<int>("ID"),Name =p.Field<string>("Name"),Role = p.Field<string>("Role"),Age = p.Field<int("Age")});
```

Comment: What is the purpose of groupbby here?

Comment: please add more information to have [a complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

Correct code:

```
var name = dt1.AsEnumerable()
                  .Where(p => p.Field<int>("Age") >= 29)
                  .GroupBy(p =>p.Field<string>("Role"))
                  .Select(q => q.Select(p => new{ID = p.Field<int>("ID"),Name =p.Field<string>("Name"),Role = p.Field<string>("Role"),Age = p.Field<int>("Age")}));
```

**Explanation:**

- GroupBy will create `IEnumerable<IGrouping<string,DataRow>>` in this case
- When you do `Select`, you get `IGrouping`, on which you need to do further `Select` to get the exact element `DataRow` used for creation of result `Anonymous Type` as in this case

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It solution worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Refer [LINQ Case statement with COUNT and GROUP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40583955/linq-case-statement-with-count-and-group) for selecting fields in group by. both Lambda exp and c# linq is available.

Comment: Please add this as a comment, there's no value add from your end